# IE9 breaking login when popping up loading message

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a form that when the submit button is clicked it popups a please wait message and the form submits. Its pretty simple, however it the form will not submit in IE9.

`<input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return process_login();" />`

Is inside of my `<form></form>`

and my `process_login()` function is

`function process_login(){
   $('#login').html('Please wait...');
   return true;
}`

If I just do `return true;` it works fine, but its like because the `#login` which is where the form is housed, is being replaced, it will not submit the form. If i just append please wait to it, then it submits. I mean, I guess I could have it hide the form and show the message. What is the best option? This works in all other browsers. Thanks.

Comment: Simply hiding the form and showing the message which looked like the same effect did work, but the initial problem still bugs me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can use the [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event to handle it instead of the `onclick` Can you try the following:

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In" id="signInButton" />

$('#signInButton').submit(function() {
    $('#login').html('Please wait...');
    return true;
})
```

If not try using the [IE Developer tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/22/ie9-developer-tools-network-tab.aspx) to look further into any javascript errors that IE is running into.

Comment: That got me the same result. The message shows but no submit. I already tried a few ways to use the submit event handler. It feels like since  the message is replacing the form entirely, that its causing it not to submit, since simply appending the message works fine. Thanks.